# Image stretching after Render

Tags: camera

Everytime I press render, the image comes out distorted, I've tried changing lens, views, type of camera to no avail.
[image]

Comment: Have you made sure, that the modifiers settings are the same for viewport and render level? [Uploading your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and add it to the question will probably get better results.

Answer (score 1):

judging from your outliner you might have a hidden mesh/object.

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>H</kbd>